# Exercise on formal group laws over an algebraically closed field

Tags: formal-groups

There is an exercise in Weinstein's notes on Lubin--Tate theory, namely show that there is a unique (up to isomorphism) one-dimensional formal group law of given finite height $h$ over an algebraically closed field of characteristic $p$. A hint is to show that for the Diedonne module $M$ of such a formal group law $\mathcal{F}$ we have $F^h(M)=pM$.

I think that to prove the latter statement we need the following facts:

- by definition, there is a power series $g(X)\in W(\bar{F_p})[[X]]$ such that $[p]_{\mathcal{F}}X=g(F^h(X))$ and such that $g'(0)\neq 0 (\mathrm{mod}\, p)$. I believe this means that we can find another power series $f\in W(\bar{F_p})[[X]]$ such that $g\circ f=1(\mathrm{mod}\,p)$.
- power series comparable $\mathrm{mod}\,p$ induce the same map on $H^1_{dR}$.
- reparametrization by a power series from $W(\bar{F_p})[[X]]$ preserves the class of closed/exact forms.

I am not sure how to proceed from here. One problem is that Frobenius does not really induce a linear map between Diedonne modules but a semi-linear map (maybe here we should use that the ground field is algebraically closed, so $g(F^h(X))=F^h(g_1(X))$ where $g_1$ is a power series whose coefficients are the inverse images of the coefficients of $g$ under the lift of $\bar{F_p}$-Frobenius to $W(\bar{F_p})$). Could somebody give a detailed proof so that a novice would understand?

Comment: I suppose you know that Lazard proved it in the old days by elementary methods, without Dieudonné modules?

Comment: @Lubin yes, I also saw an elementary proof in Strickland's notes. But I feel bad about not understanding this proof so I want to figure it out

Comment: I’m really rusty on Dieudonné-module theory, but it just seems to me that since $[p](x)$ and $\text{frob}^h(x)=x^{p^h}$ have the same kernel, the corresponding maps on the D-module level should have the same cokernel. ( You do have a sort of a typographical error in your question, by the way: the series $g$ such that $[p](x)=g(x^{p^h})$ is in $k[[x]]$, not the ring of series over the Witt vectors. Similarly, I suppose you mean for the series $f$ that’s an inverse of $g$ to have coefficients in $k$, so that $(g\circ f)(x)=x$, not $1$. )